# Count values base on other field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name `nybruker_trheim` it have lot of fields but right now i am dealing with 2 fields which are `brukergr` and `sperret` the data in these fields looks like this

```
brukergr sperret
S1         Nei
S2         Nei
S1         je
S3         Nei
S4         Nei
S5         je
S5         je
S4         Nei
S3         Nei
S5         je
```

The results i want to show is something like that

```
S1 Total nei is 1
S2 Total nei is 1
S3 Total nei is 2
S4 Total nei is 2
S5 Total nei is 0
```

I have try different quires for this but did not get any success, Here is the query i am trying right now.

```
"select sperret,
    count(case when brukergr = S1 then brukergr end) as S1,
    count(case when brukergr = S2 then brukergr end) as S2,
    count(case when brukergr = S3 then brukergr end) as S3,
    count(case when brukergr = S4 then brukergr end) as S4,
    count(case when brukergr = S4 then brukergr end) as S5
from yzb5l_chronoforms_data_nybruker_trheim
group by sperret"
```

Comment: Can write a solution in PHP or just mysql syntax only?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select brukergr,
       count(*)
from nybruker_trheim
where sperret = 'Nei'
group by brukergr
```

Comment: it will give me total Nei not for individual S1, S2, S3, S4 and S5

Comment: i got it just replace the group by with brukergr and it done. Thanks

Comment: @Aadil Yes, you are right. I've corrected my answer. Please mark this or any other answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is very hard to understand but is this what you're asking for?

```
select sperret, brukergr, count(*)
from yzb5l_chronoforms_data_nybruker_trheim
group by brukergr, sperret
```